# Compatibility issues with IE on my site

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I wanted to kindly know how I can fix a compatibility problem with IE on my site

The problem is that accented letters are not displayed correctly

these are some meta tags that I added , but the problem still persists

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> (for boostrap)
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

[this is my site](http://www.nicolomonili.it/)

thanks

Comment: could you check the charset sent from server in the response headers of your `text/html` document? have you tried to replace diacritic chars with entities (e.g. `è -> &egrave;`)?

Comment: I had a similar problem some days ago, my solution is to make the `content-type` the first line of `<head>`.

Comment: @Dylengleng , your solution did not solve the problem, thanks anyway

Comment: @Fabrizio Calderan , I tried to replace the characters with diacritical entity, but accented characters are not displayed correctly

Comment: check also your website with a validator: you have some issues on the head section (like `</script></a>`)

Comment: @Fabrizio Calderan , is the code for the histats counter

Comment: there's something wrong if it starts with `<script><a>` and it ends with `</script></a>`. Use W3C validator

Comment: is this : <script>...</script> <a><script>...</script></a> <noscript>...</noscript> , and is correct

Comment: Go fix your [HTML errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.nicolomonili.it/) first, otherwise this discussion is pointless.

Comment: my HTML code is correct , are identified errors that do not make sense (using http://validator.w3.org/)

Comment: this is a test http://nicolomonili.it/dev/test.php , in a simple page. I found what causes the problem, is a css file (custom.css). But I do not understand what in the css file will create the problem

Comment: if I remove the import css , the accented characters are displayed correctly